# How to find a set of maximum independent vectors given a matrix?

Tags: matlab, svd, eigenvector, eigenvalue

Given a matrix A, I want to find a set of maximum linearly independent columns ? I have tried use `rref(A)` in matlab, then find all the **pivot**, it works well in general matrix. But when the matrix is special, it seems given the wrong answer, for example  `A =`

```
1.6180    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000

1.0000    1.6180    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000         0

1.0000    1.0000    1.6180         0    1.0000    1.0000

1.0000    1.0000         0    1.6180         0         0

     0    1.0000    1.0000         0    1.6180         0

1.0000         0    1.0000         0         0    1.6180
```

then the `rref(A)=`

```
1.0000         0         0         0         0    0.8730

     0    1.0000         0         0         0   -1.6180

     0         0    1.0000         0         0    0.7450

     0         0         0    1.0000         0    0.4604

     0         0         0         0    1.0000    0.5396

     0         0         0         0         0         0
```

this cannot be right. because the **rank(A)=4**. I have done the search, someone said that `rref` is not accurate and SVD will help ? but I really don't know how to do it ? Help me with the example matrix A will help me much more. 3Q !

Comment: I just put your matrix in `rank(A)` and got 6.

Comment: sorry, this is a **Intermediate variable**, may not be accurate.

Comment: Huh? `rref(A)` is unity matrix.